# How can I label variables, data frame columns (full name + units) in such a way that plots, xtable, etc. will automatically use this information?

Tags: r, label, units-of-measurement, xtable, hmisc

I have just become aware of the label function in the Hmisc package. Yet, as far as I can see, this function does not solve my problem as axis labels still need to be manually specified as `xlab=label(var)`.

I don't see any solution for producing nice tables either (xtable). Are there any packages I am not aware of that provide this sort of functionality ? In sum, I would like to do the following:

- attach labels & units to variables, columns: `label(wght) <- weight; unit(var) <- 'kg'`
- print them in a nice way, such that: `wght <- c(20, 30); printnice(mean(wght)) -> '25 kg'`
- make plots, xtable use these 'nice' labels automatically

Comment: Make a reproducible example, show what the error is and show what you would like the output to be. Provide data for us to help. This is not an example we can help in any way.

Comment: This should not be seen as a bug, but as a question whether some functionality I specified above exists in R. Hence, I cannot give a reproducible example. I mentioned the Hmisc package as I think it is relevant. I do not expect this package to solve my question.